# Make sure a random generated string is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a referral system on which when a user creates an account, a string of six characters is randomly generated.

To do so, I use the gem [uniquify](https://github.com/ryanb/uniquify):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  uniquify :random_string, length: 6
end
```

For example, it creates a string like so: `"Ed3x7W"`.

Even if it is very unlikely, I'd like to find a way to make 100% sure every single string created is unique.

What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: What is very unlikely? Is it unlikely that you find a way? Or, is it unlikely that the strings are unique? If you mean the latter, I would expect the opposite.

Comment: unlikely that the strings aren't unique :)

Comment: @sawa, in the interest of saving disk space, there was no need to sign your comment. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gem does make [some checks](https://github.com/ryanb/uniquify/blob/master/lib/uniquify.rb#L6-L10) that'll give you 95%+ guarantee<sup>*</sup>.

If you want to be 100% sure, create a unique index over that column.

---

<sup>* I pulled that number out of thin air. But unless some heavily concurrent activity is going on, you should be pretty safe.</sup>

Comment: what would happen then if the gem generates a string that is already taken ? (supposing that I made the column `random_string` a unique index)

Comment: @JulesCorb: exception on save.

Comment: Alright well that's what I am going to do then :) thank you for your help !

Comment: Playing Russian roulette with a [20-round Lafaucheaux revolver](https://www.militaryfactory.com/smallarms/detail.asp?smallarms_id=315)? Nothing to worry about, 95% of the chambers are empty.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using gem you can use this `SecureRandom.hex(3)` or use base64 `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(4)` .

Add unique index validation or add validation in model for that field.

Comment: base16 strings tend to be longer (or less unique) than base62. But yes, no need to add a gem for this. Even as simple as uniquify.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are like legend to me in ror, how can i ignore your comment . :) . updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Set` (you will have to do a `require 'set'` and enter each String into the Set. After generating a String, see whether it is in the Set and if it is, generate a new one.